# Bing or Google MAPS to draw a route

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, bing-maps

i have Lattitudes and longitudes in a database, i want to draw a route using Bing or Google Maps in ASP.NET. Can any body guide me towards some example or web link to get idea how to do it?

Comment: How many coordinates do you have?  Do you have the complete route or just waypoints?  If you have the complete route you want to use a polyline, if just waypoints, you need a directions service.

Comment: I have 10 rows (lattitudes and longitudes pair), they are available in order, i want to draw a line from first point (1st row: Lattitude, Longitude) to next point (2nd row: lattitude, longitude).....last point (10th row: lattitude, longitude).  Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (at least with the Google Maps API).  But do you want the "route" to follow roads or be "as the crow flies" straight lines?

Comment: i need to draw simple line which will connect these points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest example to draw a routes using lattitudes and longitudes can be found at http://www.shabdar.org/asp-net/70-google-maps-control-for-aspnet-part-1.html

This is the same example but updated

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24468/Google-Maps-Control-for-ASP-NET-Part-1

Answer (score 0):

To Draw a Polyline (simple line connecting several points defined by their latitude and longitude), see the reference on the Polyline object:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Polylines), there is also an [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple)